# How can I manage vue-i18n localizations in separate files for each locale?

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I'm using [vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) plugin with VueJs 2.

My translation files are in a single file like this:

```js
{
 "en": {
    "users": {
      "title": "Users list",
      "menu": {
        "show_users": "Display users",
        "hands_down": "Hands down",
        "unblock_all": "Unblock all"
      }
    }
  },
  "fa": {
    "users":
  
...
```

And this is how I define the VueI18n object:

```js
import messages from '@/locales/i18n.json';

export default new VueI18n({
  locale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE || 'en',
  fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'en',
  messages: messages
})
```

How can I define each locale in a separate file?

**UPDATE:**

In my components I have to import locales using  `<i18n>` tag.
How can I import them with this approach?

```html
<i18n src="@/locales/i18n.json">
```

(This component is compiled to a web-component, then I cannot add i18n in a regular way)

Comment: Put each language into a separate json file, import them all, reform the `messages` object, and pass into `VueI18n`

Comment: You can take a look at this project https://github.com/liyasthomas/postwoman/tree/3189f46ccb89198f636095e3c78c31e78dc987ab/lang.

Comment: @EricGuan Thanks, this solves the problem. But what if I import i18n using `<i18n src="@/locales/i18n.json">`? Can I use a TS file instead of json?

Comment: Yeah, @rostamiani. You need to use a TS file inside your config file that imports all locale messages. Vuetify use this approach, see: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/tree/master/packages/vuetify/src/locale